# How to remove empty tokens/items from a json file using C#?

Tags: c#, json

How can I remove all keys that have values of `'N/A'`, `'-'`, or `''` in a json file, for example:

```
{
    "name": {
        "first": "Robert",
        "middle": "",
        "last": "Smith"
    },
    "age": 25,
    "DOB": "-",
    "hobbies": [
        "running",
        "coding",
        "-"
    ],
    "education": {
        "highschool": "N/A",
        "college": "Yale"
    }
}
```

In this scenario `middle` and `highschool` need to be removed

I tried use this:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

json.SelectTokens("@==''").FirstOrDefault().Remove();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
string jsonString = @"
    {
        ""name"": {
            ""first"": ""Robert"",
            ""middle"": """",
            ""last"": ""Smith""
        },
        ""age"": 25,
        ""DOB"": ""-"",
        ""hobbies"": [
            ""running"",
            ""coding"",
            ""-""
        ],
        ""education"": {
            ""highschool"": ""N/A"",
            ""college"": ""Yale""
        }
    }";
```

- Parse the JSON string into a JObject:

  ```
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
  ```
- Get all properties with values of "N/A", "-", or empty strings:

  ```
         var propertiesToRemove = json.Descendants()
                                  .OfType<JProperty>()
                                  .Where(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.String && 
                                    (string)p.Value == "N/A" || (string)p.Value == "-" || (string)p.Value == "").ToList();
  ```
- Remove the selected properties:

  ```
   foreach (var property in propertiesToRemove)
           {
               property.Remove();
           }
  ```

Comment: that give me this error Can not convert Object to String.' on this `p.Value.Type == JTokenType.String`

Comment: I solve it adding ( ) in this part `(string)p.Value == "N/A" || (string)p.Value == "-" || (string)p.Value == ""` and now works perfectly